# ¿Cómo resolver el error 40: "Named Pipes"?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Hice una aplicación con Windows Forms, usando Entity Framework (6), y cuando se abre el programa, lo que hace es pedirte una serie de datos para poder conectarse a la base de datos de un servidor.
Los datos que se requieren son: Nombre del servidor, nombre de la base de datos, usuario y contraseña. Como ya podrán suponer, uso estos datos para hacer una conexión la primera vez, y si esta primera conexión es exitosa, la guardo como cadena de conexión.
Este es el código:

```
EntityConnectionStringBuilder co = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
                co.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
                string s = string.Format(@"Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};User ID={2};Password={3}", SPServer.Text, SFDatabase.Text, SFUsers.Text, SFPass.Text);
                co.ProviderConnectionString = s;
                co.Metadata = "res://*/DB.csdl|res://*/DB.ssdl|res://*/DB.msl";



                try
                {
                    MDKDatabaseEntities m = new MDKDatabaseEntities(co.ToString());
                    if (m != null)
                    {
            SaveConnectionString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n" + s, "Mensaje", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
```

Entonces, para probar la conexión con la base de datos, utilicé otra computadora conectada al servidor por medio de un cable Ethernet.
La primera conexión, funciona sin problemas, pero cuando intento abrir la base de datos, me muestra el siguiente error:

> Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - No se puedo iniciar una conexión con
>   SQL Server

La computadora y el servidor comparten el mismo nombre: TLALOC. Por lo que he intentado como Data Source las siguientes variaciones, pero cada una me da otro error:

- TLALOC (Me da el error 40)
- TLALOC\\TLALOC (Me da el error 26)
- . (Me da el error 0)

¿Qué podría hacer?

Comment: Verifica que el servidor de base de datos acepte conexiones TCP.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich ¿Cómo?

Comment: Sql server configuration/ network configurarion

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich En efecto, está habilitado

Comment: Verifica si está habilitada la opción de "permitir conexiones remotas". Esto lo ves en sqlserver magnagent studio" click derecho en el server/propiedades/conexiones. Si el computador tiene firewall agregale la regla para aceptar conexiones por el puerto de sqlserver. en que linea te da error?

Answer (score 0):

Para el error 40:

Busca el administrador de configuraciones de SQL (Sql Server Configuration Manager), en tú carpeta de instalación de sql.

[image: Configuration Manager]

Si tienes varias instalaciones, busca a la que estás accediendo, y una vez la tengas seleccionada en la configuración de red, habilita el protocolo de Canalizaciones con nombre o Named Pipes si dispones de él en inglés. Una vez realizado, tienes que reiniciar el servicio del motor.

[image: Reiniciar servicio]

Guia completa de solución de problemas de conexión al motor SQL Server:

[Solución de problemas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)

[Named pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945409/how-do-i-fix-the-error-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connec)